# Difference between Javascript Injection and XSS

Tags: javascript, security, web, xss, code-injection

What is the difference between Javascript injections and XSS? I am looking for a specific answers to point a main difference in-between these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSS is the way of doing Javascript injection.

XSS is when you don't parse HTML in forms and when the content is displayed, it gets executed by the browser.
Javascript injection is when you use XSS to execute Javascript code in the browser, often to access cookies and send them to another person.